# Starting node app whenever it stops

Tags: node.js, express, npm, mean-stack, nohup

I don't have any errors in my node app, but it stops after some requests. Though i have enabled the logs and checked, its showing on different requests.

Is it possible to start the node app whenever it is stopped ?

Currently i am using this to start the node app

To start the app

`nohup npm start &`

And to find the process id

`ps aux | grep node`

And to kill certain process

`kill -9 PID`

I don't want to leave the app stopped. It should be ever running. So, Is it possible to start the app whenever it gets stopped.

Thanks

Comment: Check out forever.js

Comment: Unless you're closing the terminal on which you ran `node`  command the app should not stop without an error. I would be interested in finding the cause first.

I use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). It does restart the server if stopped.

Comment: you should use process managerment dependencies like `forever` or `pm2`, that feature is supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to monitor and restart your app for you.
By default if you run your app with PM2 it will auto-restart it if it crashes.

```
npm install pm2@latest -g
pm2 start index.js
```

PM2 can also be used to run multiple instances and has commands to stop/restart individual ones.

You can get the process PID using `pm2 list` as well.

---

More robust use case:

Start up your app by having PM2 run 'npm start' and also give it a name to refer to it later (it will auto restart if it exits/crashes)

```
pm2 start npm --name="mySuperApp" -- start
```

Later you make some changes and want to restart it:

```
pm2 restart mySuperApp
```

Eventually you want to stop the app:

```
pm2 stop mySuperApp
```

Comment: will this automatically starts if my app stops ?

Comment: Thanks pm2 made my life easy :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use nodemon

installing it with `npm install -g nodemon`

and running your code like this : `nodemon index.js`

Finding more documentation [here](http://nodemon.io/)

It will run until your app encounter an error but you can restart it with `rs` in your console

Comment: Will this automatically starts app once it encounters error ? Is there any possible way to do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is said that nodemon is more suitable in a dev environment where [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) would be the one to use in prod mode